# How to decrypt XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, encryption

How to read the encrypted file of XML in C#

Answer (score 1):

Your XML document is encrpted with what?
if you write your own Encrypt Service, u must have DeCrypt service too. So ReadXml(); , and then DeCrypt it with your service. ( Limited answer, because of your short description of your question)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Serkan.
Is the file encrypted (e.g. the data inside it looks random) in which case you need to decrypt the file and then you can read the XML as normal or.
Is the data contained within the XML encrypted (e.g. the contents of the file looks like XML however the nodes look garbage?  In this case you only have to pass the node values through your decryption routine.

I would imagine that it is more likely to be the first. But you will have to expand on your original request.  Like the type of encryption used.  I take it that you have the decyption keys etc.